# Finite union of compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that the union of two compact Hausdorff subspaces of an arbitrary space is Hausdorff? What if the ambient space is weakly Hausdorff, that is, the image of any continuous map from a compact Hausdorff space to the given space is closed? (Then it is in particular, a $T_1$-space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is no, as seen by, e.g., the indiscrete two-point space having the two single point as trivially compact Hausdorff.

The second answer is yes.

**Claim** If $K$ is compact Hausdorff, $X$ is weakly Hausdorff, $u\colon K\to X$ is continuous, then $u(K)$ is compact Hausdorff in the subspace topology inherited from $X$.

*Proof (gist)*: Let $L=u(K)$ and so $u\colon K\to L$ is closed since any closed subset $E$ of $K$ is compact Hausdorff so $u(E)$ is closed in $X$, hence in $L$ too.  If $a,b\in L$ with $a\neq b$ then $u^{-1}(a),u^{-1}(b)$ are disjoint closed subsets of $K$.  Since compact Hausdorff implies $T_4$, you can find disjoint $U,V$ in $K$ containing $u^{-1}(a)$ and $u^{-1}(b)$ respectively.  Then $U'=\{x\in X\mid u^{-1}(x)\subseteq U\}$ and similarly $V'$ shows $L$ is Hausdorff.$\quad\square$

Apply this to $i_1\cup i_2\colon K_1\amalg K_2\to X$ and you have the union.

Comment: The last proof doesn't show the *union* fact though, which was the question. The first example can work, but make it concrete and explicit.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I apply it to $u\colon K_1\amalg K_2\to X$, no?

Comment: Yes, that would work, applying the standard fact (proper/perfect image of Hausdorff is Hausdorff) to the sum of the embeddings.

Comment: @ user10354138: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

No, I think the following is a counterexample: let $X = \Bbb N \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$ and define the topology on $X$ by declaring all subsets of $\Bbb N$ open, and a subset $A \cup \{-\infty\}$ of $X$ is an open neighbourhood of $-\infty$ iff $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is finite, and similarly for $+\infty$. Then $X$ is not Hausdorff, (as witnessed by $-\infty, +\infty$) despite being the union of the compact Hausdorff subspaces $\Bbb N \cup \{+\infty\}$ and $\Bbb N \cup \{-\infty\}$ (which also have a non-compact intersection BTW).

This $X$ is not weakly Hausdorff as the embedding $N \cup \{\infty\}$ into $X$ does *not* have a closed image in $X$.

The other answer (by user10354138) shows why that is. The argument only holds for finite unions of compact Hausdorff subsets.

Comment: Thank you for the example! Sorry that I have not accepted your answer. I it was possible, I would have accepted both answers!

Comment: @Simba Did you understand the argument user103 etc gave? It’s not quite obvious and might use stuff not in your book.

Comment: Do you mean the proof of the claim or the last sentence? I have seen the claim and its proof before (in some more detail), so this is good. And when applying the claim to $K_1\bigsqcup K_2 \to X$, we get the desired result, right? Or is there something else to keep in mind? (You said something about "the standard fact (proper/perfect image of Hausdorff is Hausdorff)"...)

Comment: @Simba i meant the claim and its application. It’s all rather subtle in that weakly Hausdorff is just enough to make some proofs work.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma: If I have understood it correctly, we need the assumption that $X$ is weakly Hausdorff to make sure that points in $X$ are closed. (But actually, $T_1$ would suffice, right?) Now, given two compact Hausdorff subspaces $K_1$ and $K_2$ of $X$, $K_1\bigscup K_2$ is again compact Hausdorff, and the image of $K_1\bigscup K_2\to X$ is their union in $X$, so this is compact Hausdorff, by the claim. Is this argument correct? (Where do we need to use "the standard fact"? Or does this refer to the proof of the claim?)

Comment: @Simba $K_1 \sqcup K_2$ is indeed compact Hausdorff and the map into $K$ is $i_{K_1} \sqcup i_{K_2}$ so continuous and maps onto $K_1 \cup K_2$. By the standard fact that test maps preserve Hausdorffness we get that $K_1 \cup K_2$ is thus Hausdorff. The weakly Hausdorff property of $X$  implies also that $K_1$, $K_2$ (and their union) are actually also *closed* subsets of $X$. As singletons are compact Hausdorff it also implies $X$ is $T_1$, but the first fact is more to the point.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma: Thank you!